# Creating a class named Mailbox which uses an existing class named Message in order to add, remove, and retrieve e-mail messages stored in a list?

Tags: python

The *Message* class allows a message to be printed with a sender, recipient, and a message.  The *Mailbox* class is supposed to allow the user to add, remove, and retrieve e-mails stored based on the index.  So far, the *Message* class works correctly.  However, the *Mailbox* class does not.  The following is the code I have thus far:

```
class Message :

    def __init__(self, sender, recipient) :
        self._sender = sender
        self._recipient = recipient
        self._message = ""

    def append (self, message) :
        self._message = self._message + message

    def toString(self) :
        theMessage = "From: " + self._sender + "\n"
        theMessage = theMessage + "To: " + self._recipient + "\n"
        theMessage = theMessage + self._message
        return theMessage

class Mailbox(Message) :

    def __init__(self, messages, index) :
        self._messages = messages

    def addMessage (self, message) :
        self._messages.append(theMessage)

    def getMessage (self, index) :
        return self._messages[index]

    def removeMessage (self, index) :
        self._index = messages.pop(index)
```

I also have the test case in order to test if the classes are working:

```
from HomeworkP925 import Message, Mailbox

sender = input("Please enter the sender information: ")
recipient = input("Please enter the recipient information: ")
myMessage = Message(sender, recipient)
printedMessage = ""

textMessage = input("Please enter the email message: ")

while textMessage != "end" :
    printedMessage = printedMessage + "\n" + textMessage
    textMessage = input("> ")

myMessage.append(printedMessage)

print(myMessage.toString())

print(getMessage[index])
```

The test case prints the sender, recipient, and message fine.  But then I get the error: *name 'getMessage' is not defined* which I'm assuming is because there is no variable named *getMessage* in the test case.  How would I go about storing the printed message in a list?

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs more details about what you tried to do, what went wrong, and what error message you saw.

But, I will say, your `Mailbox.getMessage()` seems wrong.  The first line should read

```
print(self._messages[index])
```

Note the square brackets for array indexing, rather than your parentheses, which is trying to call `self._messages` like a function.  The second line should read

```
return self._messages[index]
```

since there is no such variable `messages`.  I assume you also wanted to return a particular message, indexed by `index`.

Comment: does the information I added clear anything up? If there is anything else that would help, please let me know.

Comment: The ``NameError`` is because there is no global function called ``getMessage``, which is actually a method of the ``Mailbox`` class. To get this to work, you would need to create a ``Mailbox`` instance, use the ``addMessage()`` method to put ``myMessage`` into it, and then use ``getMessage()`` to get the message back out.

I notice this is from a homework assignment. I don't think you should be asking for direct help on homework problems without putting in some more effort on the basics yourself. Maybe review the Python basics, and post questions about those if you still have trouble?